# Exporting Data from Nested Usercontrols (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I'm looking for a better way to get data from Models to export. Below I've outlined what my current strategy is, but I feel like there's a better one.

Suppose I have a control, NestingView, with a textbox, button, and itemscontrol. The button adds a new NestingView to the ItemsControl. My goal is to be able to export the data including the nesting path.

Specifically, to JSON, but that's beside the point I think. For reference, though, the result would look something like:

```
{
    "Text": "",
    "Children": []
}
```

At the moment the way I've come up with nesting the controls is to have the NestingViewModel contain ObservableCollection which is used by the items control. Saving, then, would be a matter of iterating through the collections in the collections... etc.

This, I believe, *works*, but it certainly feels dirty having VMs with VMs with VMs... so I wonder if there's a better/easier/cleaner/"more MVVM" way to do it.

For brevity I am not using a Model in this example, but suppose it would be there and would contain the validated data that is ultimately used to export. Also, note that I am using Prism.

NestingViewModel.cs

```
public class NestingViewModel : BindableBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of NestingViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public NestingViewModel()
    {
        NestingViewModels = new ObservableCollection<NestingViewModel>();
        NewNestingView = new DelegateCommand(AddNestingViewModel);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NestingViewModel> NestingViewModels { get; }

    private String _TextBody;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the text body
    /// </summary>
    public String TextBody
    {
        get => _TextBody;
        set => SetProperty(ref _TextBody, value);
    }

    public ICommand NewNestingView { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new NestingViewModel to the collection
    /// </summary>
    private void AddNestingViewModel()
    {
        NestingViewModels.Add(new NestingViewModel());
    }
}
```

NestingView.xaml

```
<Border BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" BorderThickness="5">
<StackPanel Margin="5">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextBody}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="New" Command="{Binding NewNestingView}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ItemsControl Margin="20 5 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding NestingViewModels}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:NestingView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAb98.png)

So in that example the JSON would look as follows:

```
{
    "Text": "Parent",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Text": "ChildA",
            "Children": null
        },
        {
            "Text": "ChildB",
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Text": "ChildB's ChildA",
                    "Children": null
                },
                {
                    "Text": "ChildB's ChildB",
                    "Children": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Text": "ChildA",
            "Children": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So are you asking why your code isn't working or are you asking for improvement on code architecture/pattern? I would clarify your problem you're having and explicitly say what you're asking readers to help with.

Comment: Asking for improvement suggestions

" it certainly feels dirty having VMs with VMs with VMs... so I wonder if there's a better/easier/cleaner/"more MVVM" way to do it. "

I've added a more clear opening statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it certainly feels dirty having VMs with VMs with VMs

Not at all, that's the most normal thing in the world. I'd rather say view models without children are unusual, unless you have a very simple wizard-like app.

Also, in all but proof-of-concept apps, I'd refrain from storing original data in the view model. Always try to store data in some service as models. The view model's job is to aggregate and work up the data for the view.

Comment: Sounds good, I came across many conflicting views about storing VMs in other VMs. The only thing that seems weird about it to me is that it basically precludes the usefulness of Prisms auto wiring. And yes, the data and business logic are in models, that was just a simplified example.

Comment: Auto wiring is meant only for the "root" view model, and only if you navigate view model-first.